# Postgres Searching for a value in an array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with an array column. I need to be able to search this column using `ILIKE` to see if any of the values in the array contain my search term. The column contains values like `{'123532', '343432', 243243'}`

I tried doing something like the following:

```sql
select
  *
from
  foo as f
where
  '%12%' ILIKE ANY(f.my_column)
```

This always returns an empty result. I also tried other variations like:

```sql
select
  *
from
  foo as f
where
  f.my_column @> '{%12%}'
```

However this also returns an empty result